# Decompressing gzip packets with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip, packet, scapy

I'm creating a PCAP parser and analyzer in Python with the Scapy package but I'm running into an issue where just about everything is compressed with gzip. Is there a way for me to have gzipped packet payloads decompressed as my program loops through the PCAP file?

In the packet payload there is this line:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Have a look at `zlib`, `zlib.decompress()` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gzip` module to uncompress the data

```
import StringIO
import gzip

compressed_data = f.read()
compressed_stream = StringIO.StringIO(compressed_data)
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_stream)
data = gzipper.read()
```

Like explained in http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/gzip_compression.html

Comment: Does this work if only a portion of the string being passed in is compressed by gzip? Basically, will I have to isolate the gzipped material before using this method?

Comment: I'm afraid yes, but normally the entire body of the message will be gzipped.